# Value is changed from 0 to 48 in C# when using ToCharArray()

Tags: c#

For some reason a value 0 is changed to 48 from 0. I get a string of "100" but it should be "001" so I used this code to change the order and place it in an array so I can get each value:

```
var inputArray = binarystring.ToCharArray().Reverse();
InputValues = inputArray as char[] ?? inputArray.ToArray();
```

But when I check a value, say InputValues[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoPhS.png), as a value I get 48. I just need the "0" or "1". Thank you.

Using the suggestion I still get the issue
[image]

Comment: Value is not changed at all. 48 is representation for 0 character in ASCII

Comment: Right on your screenshot you can see array contains characters '1', '0', '0'.

Comment: Yes. But when I get the value it gives me the Ascii and not the 1 or 0

Comment: _Using the suggestion I still get the issue_ What issue? Does the method reverse the string correctly or not? If you are expecting to see binary values 0x01 and 0x00, you will have to parse the characters to bytes, ints, or other numeric type.

Comment: it does reverses the message. But that is what my original code does. It reverses the message. The issue is I can't get the 1 and 0. I just get the ascii values.

Comment: You _have_ '1' and '0' as _characters_. If you want _numbers_, you have to parse the characters to a number type, either before or after reversing the array, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Akash KC, you convert it to char array, where 48 is the char '0', use below function instead:

```
public static string ReverseStringDirect(string s)
{
    char[] array = new char[s.Length];
    int forward = 0;
    for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        array[forward++] = s[i];
    }
    return new string(array);
}
```

Comment: If OP just join `InputValues` by simply calling `string reversedStr = string.Join("", InputValues);`, OP will have reverse string. I like your approach though

Comment: agree with you, @AkashKC

Comment: I need it converted to an array. I still get the 48 for 0 and 49 for 1. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Thank you for your time.